# Auto-updating filter values on DataTable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I'm currently using filters with options list on my lazy loaded DataTables. Everything works just fine except I'd like to be able to reload my filter options depending on currently selected filters.

For example, my DataTable has two fields country and region, and I want to filter

DataTable snippet :

```
<p:dataTable var="d" widgetVar="personneContactTable" value="#{bean.dataModel}" id="myDataTable" lazy="true">
    <p:column sortBy="country" filterBy="country" filterOptions="#{bean.getCountryOptions()}">
        [...]
    </p:column>
    <p:column sortBy="region" filterBy="region" filterOptions="#{bean.getRegionOptions()}">
        [...]
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

And my bean :

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
    LazyDataModel<MyStuff> dataModel;

    String country; 
    String region;

    public SelectItem[] getCountryOptions() {
        return service.someMagic();
    }

    public SelectItem[] getRegionOptions() {
        return service.someMoreMagic(country);
    }

    // + getters, setters, etc.
}
```

I tried using properties instead of methods, adding `<p:ajax event="filter">` tags to try reloading part of the DataTable, but nothing worked. I found http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=38087 too, but again not workable solution emerged.

How can I automaticaly refresh my filterOptions? (this is using Primefaces 4 ELITE branch)